# De caracter a bit

Tags: sql

Con la ayuda del CURP, sé si la persona en mis registros es Hombre o Mujer, y tengo esta consulta pequeña, pero mi duda es como puedo cambiar de caracter a bit ya que en mi intento de insertar en el campo sexo, me dice que es bit (0, 1) donde 0 = Femenino y 1 = Masculino

```
SELECT CURP, SUBSTRING(CURP, 11, 1) AS SEXO FROM Clientes
```

Comment: Puedes usar un Case WHEN SUBSTRING(CURP, 11, 1)  = 'F' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e indica en qué motor de bases de datos estás trabajando.

Comment: estas seguro que queres cambiar a bit?

Comment: A mi se me presento un problema similar al utilizar Bit en lugar de entero, ya que efectivamente al querer insertar un valor solo recibe 0 1, pero al realizar unos cambios ese 0 y 1 ya no me fue util, asi que tuve que cambiarlo a entero, y solucione mi problema, realmente necesitas que sea bit ese campo

Comment: Si no de lo contrario pues cambia en la tabla el campo a entero aunque sea de extensión o tamaño =  1 , al no ser que tengas un proceso que requiera que ese campo sea bit de lo contrario no te compliques tanto